# Mule Illegal character in query resquest

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I try to do a request with the Request
this is the URL: (Concatenated the variable with the rest of the URL)

```
vars.BaseURLOData ++ " " ++ "eq" ++ " 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'" as String

vars.BaseURLOData = http://31.192.103.112:8082//apisserver/api.src/ER_EasyApple_tbl?$filter=ER_application_id
```

The **full URL** (already concatenated) should be:

```
http://31.192.103.112:8082//apiserver/api.src/ER_EasyApple_tbl?$filter=ER_application_id eq 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'
```

But It said the following error:

```
Illegal character in query at index 88: 

http://31.192.103.112:8082//apiserver/api.src/EA_EasyApple_tbl?$filter=EA_application_id eq 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'
```

Comment: How are you using the URL I'm the HTTP connector?

Comment: I use the HTTP Request configuration
Protocol: HTTPS
Host: The host api
Port: empty

and then the basic authentication with the user and pass.

I use the same HTTP configuration in other request and it works. This makes me think that the problem is not there

Comment: The idea is to share the actual XML (as text) of the request so we can see how the connector operation is used. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Sorry this is the XML
<http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request(Select)" doc:id="d7c35e18-0cac-4d9f-832d-f094e728ee0f" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" url="#[vars.BaseURLOData ++ &quot; &quot; ++ &quot;eq&quot; ++ &quot; 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'&quot; as String]">
 <http:headers >
  <![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 "Authorization" : "Basic GHFhbhjoZXi8NnYySTB3FGw9UDl4M24wGRREK9E="
}]]]>
 </http:headers>
</http:request>

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the HTTP Request connector likes having spaces in your URL. You could try to URL encode it first using the DataWeave function [encodeURI()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-url-functions-encodeuri).

Having said that, I'm not really sure that the connector is expecting query parameters in the URL. There is a separate section for query parameters in the connector.

The usual form would be something like this:

```
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/apiserver/api.src/EA_EasyApple_tbl" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP Request">
                <http:query-params>#[
                    {
                        filter : "EA_application_id eq 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'"
                    }
                ]</http:query-params>
```

Protocol, Host and port are defined in the configuration of the connector.

Comment: how would it be in this case?

Comment: <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request(Select)" doc:id="d7c35e18-0cac-4d9f-832d-f094e728ee0f" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration2" path="/apiserver/api.src/EA_EasyApple_tbl">
 <http:headers >
  <![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 "Authorization" : "Basic GHFhbhjoZXi8NnYySTB3FGw9UDl4M24wGRREK9E="
}]]]>
 </http:headers>
 <http:query-params >
  <![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 "$filter" : "EA_application_id eq 'x1543b14-6f7f-4dc0-a6ga-d0574e9c80ae'"
}]]]>
 </http:query-params>
</http:request>

Comment: "Cannot coerce Function (org.mule.weave.v2.runtime.core.functions.OverloadedFunctionValue@3140713c) to String
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: "output application/java
---
{
"$filter" : "EA_application_id eq 'c1343b04-6f7f-4dc0-a2ba-d0374e9c46ae'"
}".

This is the new error that it show me

Comment: Try escaping the character `$`. It is the string interpolation operator. Try with `"\$filter"`.